# window.print not printing input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I'm printing a part of page, The page has dynamic content and element.
I'm wondering I can't print values of **input and select** element.
I tried many things over there but none of them worked in my case.
Code is given below.

```
       <div class="panel-body" id="printable">
            <style type="text/css">
                .italic{
                    font-style: italic;
                }
                table tr th,table tr td{
                    text-align: center;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                }
                .justify{
                    text-align: justify;
                }
                .form-control{
                    border-color: #ffffff;
                    border-style: none;
                    padding: 0px;
                }
            </style>
            <center class='italic'>
                <strong>ANNEXURE - 1</strong><br>
                GATE PASS
            </center>
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="col-xs-5 italic">1. Unit's Name & Address </span>
                    <span class="col-xs-1">:</span>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <select class="form-control css-select" name="party" id="party">
                            <?php
                                foreach ($parties as $p) {
                                    echo "<option data-add='$p->address' value='$p->name'>$p->name</option>";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="party_address" id="party_address"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="col-xs-5 italic">C.H.A</span>
                    <span class="col-xs-1">:</span>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        SELF
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="col-xs-5 italic">2. Suppliers' Name & Address </span>
                    <span class="col-xs-1">:</span>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <input class="form-control" name="supplier" id="supplier" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <input class="form-control" name="supplier_add" id="supplier_add" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="col-xs-5 italic">3. Vehicle No </span>
                    <span class="col-xs-1">:</span>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <input class="form-control" name="vehicle" id="vehicle">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table width="100%" border="1px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width='10%'>Sr. No</th>
                        <th width='40%'>Description of the Goods</th>
                        <th width='20%'>Invoice No / Challan with Date</th>
                        <th width='15%'>No of Pkgs / Qty in CBM</th>
                        <th width='14%'>Values(Rs.)</th>
                        <th width='1%' id='pls_th'><i id='pls_btn' class='fa fa-plus' style="cursor:pointer"></i></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="data_part">
                    <tr class='tdss'>
                        <td><input name='sr1' id='sr1' class='form-control sr' data-count='1'></td>
                        <td><input name='description1' id='description1' class='form-control desc'></td>
                        <td><input name='inv_date1' id='inv_date1' class='form-control inv'></td>
                        <td><input name='pack1' id='pack1' class='form-control pack'></td>
                        <td><input name='value1' id='value1' class='form-control val'></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="row"><br>
                <div class="col-xs-12">5. Purpose for which the Item (s) is/are taken inside the Zone</div>
                <div class="col-xs-5">1. Capital Goods ( X )</div>
                <div class="col-xs-5">2. Consumables ( X )</div>
                <div class="col-xs-5">3. Raw Materials ( X )</div>
                <div class="col-xs-5">4. Components ( X )</div>
                <div class="col-xs-5">5. Packing Materials ( X )</div>
                <div class="col-xs-5">6. Miscellaneous ( * )</div>
                <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-5">7. Office use ( X )</div>
            </div><br>
            <center class='row'>DECLARATION</center>
            <div class="row col-xs-12 justify">I/We hereby declaration......</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <center>Signture <br>
                        For <span id='party_for'></span><br><br>
                        Authorised Signatory<br><br>
                        Accepted
                    </center>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 form-horizontal">
                    <span class="col-xs-6 control-label"><strong>Date & Time : </strong></span>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <input name='date_time' id="date_time" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y"); ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <center>
                        Signature of the Check<br><br>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Js

```
    $("#pls_btn").click(function() {
        var co = "";
        $(".sr").each(function() {
            co = $(this).data('count');
        });
        co = co+1;
        var htm = "<tr id='tr"+co+"' class='tdss'><td><input name='sr"+co+"' id='sr"+co+"' class='form-control sr' data-count='"+co+"'></td><td><input name='description"+co+"' id='description"+co+"' class='form-control desc'></td><td><input name='inv_date"+co+"' id='inv_date"+co+"' class='form-control inv'></td><td><input name='pack"+co+"' id='pack"+co+"' class='form-control pack'></td><td><input name='value"+co+"' class='form-control val'></td><td width='1%'><i  class='fa fa-minus minus' style='cursor:pointer' data-id='"+co+"'></i></td></tr>";
        $("#data_part").append(htm);
        console.log(htm);
    });
```

Print button js

```
$("#print").click(function() {
    var link = "<link href='<?php echo base_url('../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>' rel='stylesheet' />";
    var cont = link+$("#printable").html();
    var wind = window.open("","",params);
    setTimeout(function (){
        wind.document.write(cont);
    },1000);
    setTimeout(function (){
        wind.print();
        wind.close();
    },2000);

});
```

What can I do in this situation.
Thanks.

Comment: `wind.print()`? Maybe `window.print()`

Comment: I have defined wind above. look. print window appears but input and select element is not printing with values. @JustARandomProgrammer

Comment: `wind` is defined as `window.open()`

Comment: yes, and works fine. That is not the problem. @JustARandomProgrammer

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I tried fiddle but something went wrong, so couldn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147925/discussion-between-chigs-and-justarandomprogrammer).